# Get statistic of record counts from FileMaker using AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript, filemaker

Can somebody advise whether there's a good built-in way (= AppleScript command) to pull out statistics for a DB:

I need to count the number of occurrences of a string in a particular field over all records.

E.g. for a record that has

- *Name*
- *Phone*
- *Town*

the script would return how many records exist with identical towns.

Comment: **FWIW:** Still interested in a FM approach - However, for now I've reverted to pulling out the fields of all records with AppleScript as a concatenated string and doing a little bit of post-processing from Cocoa in 4 lines of code, splitting the `NSString` and feeding a `NSCountedSet` to get the stats..

Comment: Your question looks like you're asking for an AppleScript approach to the data but your comments indicate you're looking for a FM approach. Which are you looking for and do you have the ability to modify the database structure?

Comment: I'm looking for an AppleScript that's using FileMaker AppleScript commands to return the statistics to an external application! I.e. take an existing DB and query it for the statistics w/o modifying it in any way..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1 - Create a relationship.
 - File > Manage Database > Define Database
 - Relationships tab
 - Duplicate your table occurance and name it (I used `related_towns`)
 - Drag a relationship between the two from town to town
 - Click OK.

[image: This is what your relationships tab should look like]

Step 2 - Create a calculated field that counts the instances of the related (duplicative) town name.

- File > Manage Database > Define Database
- Fields Tab
- Type in the name of your new field (I used `number_of_related_towns`) at the bottom of the screen
- Select "Calculation" from the field type list
- Count the times that the town appears in your relationship with this calcuation:

[image: This is what your calculation field should look like]

Be sure that "Evaluate this calculation in the context of" is set to the name of your base table (what your layout is based on). Replace `related_towns` with whatever you named your new table occurance.

Step 3 - Write a script to display your data.

- Scripts > Manage Scripts
- New button (bottom left)
- Rebuild the screenshot below. I added comments, which hopefully explain?

[image]

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Cheers, that's working fine! Would be nice to know if the Calculation functions like `Count` are accessible via AppleScript, though.

Comment: No FileMaker functions are accessible via applescript, to the best of my knowledge. You can, however, call AppleScript from within FileMaker.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in FileMaker. It is built for exactly this. Do you know how to do it in FM?

Comment: That was my starting point but apparently no one knows how to do it :-)

Comment: All sorts of ways to do this in FileMaker. Adding additional answer now.